# Want to compare string with null iOS sdk

Tags: ios, null

I want to comapre my string with null values I am getting from my local database.

I tried `if (exe_lbl_data.text==nil)` and also `if (exe_lbl_data.text=@"(null)")` but both are showing false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try one or both of the following:

```
if (nil == str || NSNull.null == (id)str) {
  …
}
```

In this case, you need to define what Null is. There is a Null type (NS/CF-Null), and there is the concept of the Null pointer. It varies by case (that is, what is returned to you?).

Answer (score 2):

try below statement :

```
[string length] == 0
```

or

```
[string isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
```